# How do I autostart a script in terminal mode based on keyboard activity?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, screensaver, command-line-interface

I have a box running Debian command line only, and attached to a monitor. It is always on, displaying its terminal screen on my mini LCD monitor. I want a screensaver for the terminal, and seem to have found one (cmatrix, aafire). I just dont know how to launch the screensaver after 60 minutes of no keyboard input on the local monitor.

How do I launch a specific script or program on the local terminal after say 60 minutes of keyboard inactivity?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this  thread 
https://superuser.com/questions/638357/execute-a-command-if-linux-is-idle-for-5-minutes

You could just use xprintidle to queries the X server for the  user's idle  time.